# How do I begin a composition event when programmatically focusing on an input/textarea element?

Tags: javascript, html

[CompositionEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompositionEvent) are triggered on an input field when a user types in text using an IME, like when typing Chinese with a Pinyin keyboard.

I want the input to gain focus when I type anywhere on the web page. To do so I've attached a listener to the keydown event and call focus on the element:

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

function handleEvent(event) {
  console.log(event.type);
  console.log(event.data);
}

function handlekeydown(event) {
  inputElement.focus()
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", handlekeydown)

document.body.addEventListener("compositionstart", handleEvent);
document.body.addEventListener("compositionupdate", handleEvent);
document.body.addEventListener("compositionend", handleEvent);
```

And this works fine, but it does not carry over the composition event after focusing. So for example, if I type 'ren' in the input, 'r' is finalized into the input and then the IME menu opens for 'en':

[image]

But what I really want is for the IME menu to open for 'ren':

[image]